# Can I put mealybug-infested kale in my compost?

Tags: compost, mealybugs, kale

I have a huge infestation of mealybugs in my kale. Am I able to compost these plants or will I risk contamination?

Answer (score 2):

If your compost gets to high temperatures and you turn it over so it all gets "cooked" then it's fine.  Mealy bug are tough and persistent so given the chance of reintroducing them I would not reuse the compost for any vegetables. Perhaps outside?